# Select a value from a table using a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to select a value from a table based on a value in a dropdown menu. I have this so far:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive" id="rates">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: "><th>State</th><th>Fee1</th><th>Fee2</th><th>Fee3</th><th>Fee4</th><th>Fee5</th><th>Fee6</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="rates">
        <tr><td id="AR">Arkansas</td><td id="AR_F1">.04</td><td id="AR_F2">0.00</td><td id="AR_F3">0.00</td><td id="AR_F4">0.00</td><td id="AR_F5">0.00</td><td id="AR_F6">0.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="AZ">Arizona</td><td id="AZ_F1">.03</td><td id="AZ_F2">0.002</td><td id="AZ_F3">0.00</td><td id="AZ_F4">0.00</td><td id="AZ_F5">0.00</td><td id="F6_O">0.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="CA">California</td><td id="CA_F1">.03</td><td  id="CA_F2">0.002</td><td id="CA_F3">0.00</td><td id="CA_F4">0.00</td><td id="CA_F5">0.00</td><td id="CA_F6">0.00</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table><br/>

<select id="stateSel">
      <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option value="California">California</option>
    </select><br/>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr><td><h4>Tax Calculator</h4></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee1:</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee2:</th><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee3:</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee4:</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Total:</th><td><input type="text" id="totalAmount"/></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
```

My script so far is this:

```
<script> 


function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("stateSel").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("stateSel").options;
    var rowIndex = y[x];
    var fee1 = document.getElementById("rates").rows[rowIndex.index + 1].cells[2].value;

    alert(fee1.index);
}
 </script>
```

I'm using the alert to see if I can select a value from the table with rates. I keep getting an undefined value. Later, I want to use that value (from an appropriate row and column), along with other similarly selected values, to build a fee calculator. Help me get the values from table's rows and columns please.

Comment: Do the rows and the dropdown options have the same order? (I mean the cities are they in the same order in both the table and the select?)

Comment: There are no cities. There are states in the dropdown and in the rates table as rows. The columns in rates table are different fees. Staes are in the same order in both.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't use `value` on anything other than form fields. For all other elements, use **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** or **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("stateSel").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("stateSel").options;
    var rowIndex = y[x];
    var fee1 = document.getElementById("rates").rows[rowIndex.index + 1].cells[2].textContent;

    alert(fee1);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive" id="rates">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: "><th>State</th><th>Fee1</th><th>Fee2</th><th>Fee3</th><th>Fee4</th><th>Fee5</th><th>Fee6</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="rates">
        <tr><td id="AR">Arkansas</td><td id="AR_F1">.04</td><td id="AR_F2">0.00</td><td id="AR_F3">0.00</td><td id="AR_F4">0.00</td><td id="AR_F5">0.00</td><td id="AR_F6">0.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="AZ">Arizona</td><td id="AZ_F1">.03</td><td id="AZ_F2">0.002</td><td id="AZ_F3">0.00</td><td id="AZ_F4">0.00</td><td id="AZ_F5">0.00</td><td id="F6_O">0.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="CA">California</td><td id="CA_F1">.03</td><td  id="CA_F2">0.002</td><td id="CA_F3">0.00</td><td id="CA_F4">0.00</td><td id="CA_F5">0.00</td><td id="CA_F6">0.00</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table><br/>

<select id="stateSel">
      <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option value="California">California</option>
    </select><br/>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr><td><h4>Tax Calculator</h4></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee1:</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee2:</th><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee3:</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee4:</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Total:</th><td><input type="text" id="totalAmount"/></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well. The benefit of @CodeWizard answer is that eh values in the dropdown and the values in the rates table don't have to be in the same order.

Comment: @TomBB True, but that wasn't what your question was about.

Comment: Stack Overflow never ceases to amaze. A downvote for the correct answer with explanation and references to external resources.

Answer (score 1):

Change the select to this:

```
<select id="stateSel">
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
</select><br/>
```

Use this function which will grab the content

```
/**
 ** Define your own function and documentation
 **/
function myFunction() {
    var
        // Get the selected country. It should be the value of your option
        state = document.querySelector('#stateSel').value,

        // Get the value (text) of any selected _FX from the table
        fee1 = document.querySelector('#' + state + '_F1').textContent;

    alert(fee1);
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "innerHTML" to pull the right data... See this fiddle for the solution

https://jsfiddle.net/shemdani/t5fmzbw4/7/

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive" id="rates">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: "><th>State</th><th>Fee1</th><th>Fee2</th><th>Fee3</th><th>Fee4</th><th>Fee5</th><th>Fee6</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ratesBody">
        <tr><td id="AR">Arkansas</td><td id="AR_F1">.04</td><td id="AR_F2">0.00</td><td id="AR_F3">0.00</td><td id="AR_F4">0.00</td><td id="AR_F5">0.00</td><td id="AR_F6">0.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="AZ">Arizona</td><td id="AZ_F1">.03</td><td id="AZ_F2">0.002</td><td id="AZ_F3">0.00</td><td id="AZ_F4">0.00</td><td id="AZ_F5">0.00</td><td id="F6_O">0.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="CA">California</td><td id="CA_F1">.03</td><td  id="CA_F2">0.002</td><td id="CA_F3">0.00</td><td id="CA_F4">0.00</td><td id="CA_F5">0.00</td><td id="CA_F6">0.00</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table><br/>

<select id="stateSel">
      <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option value="California">California</option>
    </select><br/>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr><td><h4>Tax Calculator</h4></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee1:</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee2:</th><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee3:</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Fee4:</th><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Total:</th><td><input type="text" id="totalAmount"/></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<button onClick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

<script>
function calculate(){
   var x = document.getElementById("stateSel").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("stateSel").options[x].value;
    alert ('selected state: ' + y);
    var rowIndex = x;
    var fee1 = document.getElementById("rates").rows[rowIndex + 1].cells[1].innerHTML;
    alert(fee1);
}

</script>
```

Comment: How is that answer different from mine, other than yours is technically incorrect since you don't "need" to use `innerHTML`. You can (and here, you should) use `textContent`.

Comment: I never said my answer is different than yours. When I posted my answer there were already 3 answers posted which I didn't even realize... BTW innerHTML is right approach. Happy to discuss this further!

Comment: My point was that when you post an answer that is fundamentally the same as one that is already posted, it isn't very good Stack Overflow etiquette. Also, `innerHTML` is only the right way if you want HTML. `textContent` is the right way if you don't and is better in those situations because of performance.

Comment: Agree on "textContent" and I hope you understand that I did not just copy your answer. The truth is I was working on solution and when I posted it, I realized there were other answers already there. I did not feel like deleting my answer after spending the time that i did... peace!